# Adding to, Not Overriding a Template Block

Tags: python, django

I have a block of code in a Django template for a simple blog engine:

```
    {% block mainLeft %}
    <section class="container" id="main">
        <section class="offset1 span8" id="mainLeft">
        </section>
    {% endblock %}
```

What would the correct way to add content within the `#mainleft` section for different templates be? For instance, if I wanted to dynamically generate divs within the section tag based on info passed in from a context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `{{ block.super }}` in the block. [See the docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/templates/#template-inheritance)